# How to recover locally deleted files that has not been committed after changes

Tags: git

I have a folder that all files have been deleted. I can see all the files by doing this command :

```
git ls-files --deleted
```

I've made locally changes that have not been added/committed.

How can I restore all the files with my last modifications ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can't. You can restore anything you showed Git with `git add`, but any content you haven't added to the repository isn't in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `git status` you will be given some information about the current state and what you could do.

You may recover a locally deleted file, to a state known to git, with:

```
git checkout -- <file>
```

Any changes made to the file is lost if you have not staged it (`git add <file>`) before you deleted it.

Some IDE:s keeps a local history of files changed by the IDE, maybe you could find  your changes there after you restored them from git.